# Java functions to encode Windows-1252 to UTF-8 getting the same symbol

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem about the conversion between the encoding Windows-1252 to UTF-8.

I have a string encoded in Windows-1252 (e.g. the character: ¢). I would like to obtain the same symbol, but encoded in UTF-8. I mean: the source character and the destination character I would like that appear always the same (¢) but with different encoding.

Is it possible? In addition: is there a Java function which performs this conversion automatically (e.g. by passing the starting encoding and the end encoding)?

Comment: Show us your code. Strings don't have any encoding. Byte streams contain encoded characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transcode between various encodings using strings as an intermediary:

```
byte[] windows1252 = { (byte) 0xA2 };
String utf16 = new String(windows1252, Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
byte[] utf8 = utf16.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

`char` data is always UTF-16 in Java.

Comment: Hi @mcDowell and thanks for your reply. My code is the following: Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Charset windows1252charset = Charset.forName("Windows-1252");

ByteBuffer inputBufferByteBuffer.wrap(str_Latin.getBytes("Windows-1252"));
CharBuffer data=windows1252charset.decode(inputBuffer);
ByteBuffer outputBuffer = utf8charset.encode(data); byte[] byUTF8 = outputBuffer.array(); str_UTF8 = new String(byUTF8, "UTF-8");

Comment: Please could you help to understand what is the problem?

Comment: Your code does `UTF-16 (char) -> Windows-1252 (byte) -> UTF-16 (char) -> UTF-8 (byte) -> UTF-16 (char)`. If it is a String it is UTF-16. There is no such thing as a UTF-8 or Windows-1252 string in Java - they must be represented by byte types.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. Since I have to write the output encoded in UTF-8 on a text file, how can I perform this transformation from a byte array (encoded with UTF-8) to string to write on a file, keeping the same symbol? Do you any advise or a function which perform this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can write byte array data to an _OutputStream_ directly. If you want to save strings (UTF-16) as UTF-8 use an _OutputStreamWriter_ with the _Charset_ constructor argument.